# python email script loop error want to know every iteration

Tags: python, email

```
for i in contacts:
    server.sendmail(user, contacts, message)
    print(f"successfully sent email to {i} and wait for 10 seconds" )
    time.sleep(10)
```

i made a python email script. This contact is a list of email addresses. The problem is on every loop iteration it keeps sending email to all contacts. But i want to print email with its sending confirmation. Please can anybody help. And i want to give loop the rest of 30 seconds after every iteration. Is it possible to do so. Or is there any other way to do thi stask. And lead please

Comment: It's sending the email because you are calling `server.sendmail()` in every iteration on all the contacts. I think you should change the second argument of that function call to `i` (or preferably a more descriptive iterator name).  Also just change the last line of the loop to `time.sleep(30)` to sleep for 30 seconds between iterations

Comment: @Matt can i do this in one line ? Is it possible ?